# Geopandas and Google Colab issue: Spatial indexes require either `rtree` or `pygeos`

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, geopandas

I am trying to do an intersection with 2 GeoDataFrame using the gdf.overlay function on Google Colab. Please see the code below

```py
!sudo apt install libspatialindex-dev
!sudo pip3 install rtree
!pip install pygeos

overlap = gpd.overlay(gdf1,gdf2, how='intersection')
overlap.plot(figsize=(10,10), cmap='jet')
```

and I get the following error message

```py
ImportError: Spatial indexes require either `rtree` or `pygeos`. See installation instructions at https://geopandas.org/install.html
```

What is causing the issue here?

Comment: You used both `pip` and `pip3`. They likely operate on different python installations

Comment: use `conda` to install `rtree` and update your python to `cpython` using `conda-forge`.

Comment: Try using a venv (`python3 -mvenv your-virtual-env`), then avoid (always!) `sudo pip`. pip-installing packages, once you have activated our virtual-env, shoud produce a coherent library ecosystem in a more reliable way.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue with running this on colab, it's because of dependencies, follow the same order as suggested in:
https://geopandas.org/getting_started/install.html

For me, error gone when I first installed dependencies:

```
!pip install pandas fiona shapely pyproj rtree
```

and then:

```
!pip install geopandas
```

Comment: For me, this did not work.

Comment: Thank you so much it works fine for me, uninstalling my geopandas first

Comment: Note that as mentioned in the [`geopandas.sindex.SpatialIndex.query` doc](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sindex.SpatialIndex.query.html#geopandas-sindex-spatialindex-query), if performance is an issue, prefer using [`pygeos`](https://pygeos.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) as a "backend" instead of `rtree`.